# putty telnet strange response when connecting with serial cable to device

Tags: telnet, putty

when I connect a serial cable to my pfsense router and starts telnet I get a a strange response. It is not the same response each time but guaranteed unreadable. Here is the latest three atempts are listed below.

I have tried to change different settings in Putty. If I change translation to UTF-8 I just get another unreadable output so guess it is not translation.

I have tried from two Windows computers using Putty. Two serial cables (same type though). I can connect to other devices with no problem.

```
--first time--
@àø
    éâ!ÀüüüBà!!!!!!!!ð@ü
                        üü
                          üBî
--Second time--
Àü
  üüü
     ü
      ø@Àÿ
          ü!a!!À!@0ðÊ

--Third time--
@ÿüüüüü!øüÿ
           0ÀÿBÀ!!!!!a!!!°üâ
```

UPDATE:

Vender tells me that it happens when the device cannot boot. So no putty error or anything. Just a faulty piece of hardware failing to boot.

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Perhaps this should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

It was faulty hardware failing to boot. Not a problem with putty or telnet.